# Error: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mvc

me aparecio este error y nosé qué es:

**jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML') TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')
at HTMLTableRowElement.**

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')
at HTMLTableRowElement.**

Me aparece en el script de mi vista la cual tiene una tabla, que recupera datos del controlador con un input hidden. Todo eso lo hace bien.

Esta es el input que recibe los valores:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="valoresParametros" name="valoresParametros" value="@ViewBag.valoresParametros" />
```

Este es el codigo que me tira error:

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            let mods = $('#valoresParametros').val().split(',');

            console.log(mods.length);
            console.log(mods);
            if (mods) {
                $('#mytable').find('tr.datos').each(function () {
                    for (let i = 0; i < mods.length; i++) {

                        if (mods[i] != null) {
                            $(this).find("td.valor")[i].innerHTML = mods[i];
                        } else {
                            $(this).find("td.valor")[i].innerHTML = " ";
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    </script>
```

el input hidden me recupera bien los valores.

Aca lo que hago (o intento de hacer) es que los valores del input hidden se carguen en la celda correspondiente de la tabla, solo utilizo una sola columna, lo único que cambian es la fila

```
if (mods[i] != null) {
                            $(this).find("td.valor")[i].innerHTML = mods[i];
}
```

Adjunto el `<tbody> </tbody>` por si lo quieren ver:

```
  <tbody>
                @foreach (var p in Model)
                {
                    <tr class="datos">
                        <td style="text-align: center">@p.Parametros.Modulos.Nombre</td>

                        <td style="text-align: center">@p.Parametros.Nemonico</td>

                        <td id="@p.CanalId" style="text-align: center">@p.Canales.Nombre</td>

                        <td class="valor" name="ValorDefault" id="@p.ParametroId @p.CanalId" style="text-align: center" contenteditable="true"></td>

                        <td><button type="button" name="boton" id="@p.CanalId @p.ParametroId" value="@p.ValorDefault" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" contenteditable="false" onclick="AgregarValor('@p.ValorDefault', @p.ParametroId, @p.CanalId)">Default</button></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se presenta porque this dentro de una funcion anonima crea un nuevo scope asi que no estas haciendo uso con $(this) del scope que rodea la funcion sino de uno nuevo, podrias superar ese error usando .bind(this) al final de la funcion anonima, sin embargo no estoy seguro que eso funcione (ya que parece que usas jquery y no lo conozco muy bien)

```
each(function () {}.bind(this)
```

Como no se mucho de jQuery lo que debes usar a mi parecer es lo siguiente, cambiar el codigo debajo de la linea que compara si mods[i] es nulo de `$(this)` por `$('#mytable')`.

```
if (mods[i] != null) {
    $('#mytable').find("td.valor")[i].innerHTML = mods[i];
} else {
    $('#mytable').find("td.valor")[i].innerHTML = " ";
}
```

Comment: Buenas! Muchas gracias! En principio me funciona bien, pero si hago alguna filtracion hay datos que no se me terminan guardando, se me "borran", pero en principio me funciono! me sirvió de mucha ayuda!! Gracias!